# Which dx do I choose for np.gradient argument?

Tags: numpy, gradient

I wont be to specific but I have a graph  E vs T ( T being the independent quantity)
I want the derivative of E with respect to T. I am unsure what dx spacing I should choose?

Details:

T = 10**(np.arange(-1,1.5,0.05))   (I.e the spacing is not equal)
E is a function of T.

Questions:

Which spacing do I use?

My thoughts:

I think I take the spacing of T i.e np.gradient(Energy, dx = T) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-uniform spacing, pass in an array of positional values (not differences) which `gradient` will to use to calculate `dx` for each point.  That is, pass in the array of absolute positions, not differences.  So in your case, just pass in `T`.

Here's an example, as a test, where the blue is the curve and red is the calculated gradients.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = 10**(np.arange(-1,1.5,0.05))

E = T**2
gradients = np.gradient(E, T)

plt.plot(T, E, '-o') # plot the curve
for i, g in enumerate(gradients): # plot the gradients at each point
    plt.plot([T[i], T[i]+1], [E[i], E[i]+g], 'r')
```

Here's the line from the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) that's of interest:

> 3. N arrays to specify the coordinates of the values along each dimension
>    of F. The length of the array must match the size of the corresponding
>    dimension